# custom permalink for single post category

Tags: rewrite-rules

Creating a custom permalink for a specific post category.
I've got this, and it works great, except, it's performing a redirect, not a rewrite.
When viewing The URL bar should still show:
`example.com/new_slug/name-of-my-post`  not redirect to `example.com/name-of-my-post`

```
// Changes permalink to add new path, if in this category
add_filter( 'post_link', 'pl_custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function pl_custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
  global $post;
  if ( has_category( 'My Category', $post->ID) ) {
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/new_slug/'. $post->post_name . '/' ) );
  }
  return $permalink;
}
add_action('init', 'pl_custom_rewrite_rules');
function pl_custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^/new_slug/(.*)$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `pl_custom_rewrite_rules()` function, change the REGEX pattern to `^new_slug/(.*)$` as in:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^new_slug/(.*)$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

because WordPress strips the preceeding `/` from the request *path* ([`WP::$request`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L53)), so using the `^/new_slug` never evaluates to `true`.

---

Additionally, in the `pl_custom_permalink()` function, remove the `global $post;` line because the function already receiving the proper post data (i.e. `$post`) as in `function pl_custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename )`.

---

The full code I used, without any re-indentation: *(tried & tested working on WordPress 4.9.8)*

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'pl_custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function pl_custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
  if ( has_category( 'My Category', $post->ID) ) {
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/new_slug/'. $post->post_name . '/' ) );
  }
  return $permalink;
}
add_action('init', 'pl_custom_rewrite_rules');
function pl_custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^new_slug/(.*)$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

---

Here's the code for the *canonical* redirect, which redirects `example.com/name-of-my-post` to `example.com/new_slug/name-of-my-post`:

```
add_action( 'wp', function( $wp ){
    // If it's a single Post and it's in the 'My Category' category, redirect to
    // the canonical version. Also check if the request path doesn't start with
    // new_slug/ as in http://example.com/new_slug/hello-world/
    if ( ! preg_match( '#^new_slug/#', $wp->request ) &&
        is_singular() && in_category( 'My Category' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a 404 error, and it neither rewrites nor redirects.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Btw, the `init` hook doesn't pass any parameters to its callback functions - e.g. your `pl_custom_rewrite_rules()` function. So the `$wp_rewrite` in that function is a `null`, unless you do something like `global $wp_rewrite;` from within the function. Also, in the `pl_custom_permalink()` function, you're not using the passed `$leavename` variable. So I'm saying that, I used your exact code so that you could easily compare the code I used with the original one. =)

Comment: And, you did flush the rewrite rules? (Visit the Permalink Settings page)

Comment: Working now.  Probably the rewrite cache.  I also did remove the unnecessary variables (from a past alliteration.)  Now I have two versions of the same page, one with and one without the new path.  Will this hurt as far as canonical pages go?

Comment: So, would you accept or upvote the answer?..

Comment: And as for the canonical thing, although I'm not very experienced in SEO, I'd suggest you to apply a *canonical redirect* on the non-canonical version of the same page — i.e. redirect users on the post with the default permalink (structure) to the `/new_slug/{SLUG}/` version. That option would be the easiest in terms of preventing penalty for duplicate content, and I can show sample code, if you want.

Comment: So Sally CJ, you suggest if the user hits the default page of /{SLUG}/ naturally, and it's not a rewritten URL, we can redirect them (301) to the new URL?  I would love to see some code for that, PLEASE!?!

Comment: Yes, @DeCoder, we can and we should perform the redirect. I'll add the code soon.

Comment: That actually opened another can of worms.  I've posted to a new thread:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/315026/wp-redirect-based-on-a-post-category

Comment: So I read the question (before you deleted it..), and you should actually check that the `$wp->request` does *not* start with `new_slug/`. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Ignore that one.  I was dealing with some caching issues.  All is good.